# Странное поведение std::reduce

Tags: c++, map-reduce

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int CountWords(string_view str) {
    auto op = [](int accum, char c) -> int {
        return accum + ((c == ' ') ? 1 : 0);
    };

    return std::reduce(str.begin(), str.end(), (int)0, op);
}

int main() {
    // должно вывести 6
    cout << CountWords("pretty little octopus dnskdj kjanfkj snfs jknds"sv) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что не так с этим кодом? Почему он выводит 2 вместо 6? Код должен посчитать пробелы в строке

Comment: @Harry, компилирую в CLion, компилятор /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13. Получается, что-то не то с GCC 13?

Comment: Во дела!!! Попробовал скомпилировать с Clang (libc++) и все нормально, тоже 6 выходит. Но что более странно, это то что std::reduce в libc++ теперь работает!!! Что за чертовщина такая?!

Comment: Но политики выполнения execution::par все равно не работают...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перепутали алгоритм. То, что вам нужно `::std::accumulate`, a `::std::reduce` - это обобщенная сумма. При его выполнении первый элемент в функторе может быть значением символа из входящей строки, а не накопленное значение.

Обратите внимание на требования алгоритма:

> T must meet the requirements of *MoveConstructible*. and `binary_op(init, *first)`, `binary_op(*first, init)`, `binary_op(init, init)`, and `binary_op(*first, *first)` must be convertible to `T`.

В этом легко убедиться, напечатав значения, поступающие в функтор:

```
auto op = [](int accum, char c) -> int {
        ::std::cout << accum << " \"" << c << "\"\n";
        return accum + ((c == ' ') ? 1 : 0);
    };
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/WExn3o4rf)

> 112 "r"
> 101 "t"
> 112 "e"
> 0 "p"
> 116 "y"
> 32 "l"
> 116 " "
> 0 "u"
> 105 "t"
> 116 "l"
> 105 "t"
> ...

При вызове `accumulate` происходит то, что вы предполагаете - для каждого элемента вызывается функтор в котором первым аргументом идет накопитель, а вторым - символ из входящей строки. При вызове `reduce` в функтор и первым, и вторым аргументом могут подавать и накопитель и символы. `reduce` может складывать элементы последовательности между собой (а может и не складывать).

Также важное отличие заключается в требовании ко входящим итераторам - `accumulate` работает с *input iterator* и поэтому работает всегда последовательно и не поддерживает параллелизм, а `reduce` имеет перегрузку с *forward iterator* и может быть выполнен параллельно.

Пример для суммирования массива:

accumulate

```
4 9 8 5 2 1 0 6
 13 ┘ │ │ │ │ │
   21 ┘ │ │ │ │
     26 ┘ │ │ │
       28 ┘ │ │
         29 ┘ │
           29 ┘
             35
```

reduce

```
4 9 8 5 2 1 0 6
 13  13   3   6
   26       9
       35
```

Для использованиея `reduce` функтор необходимо переписать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <numeric>

using t_Accum = ::std::size_t;

class t_CountSpaces final
{
    private: auto operator ()(char const ch) const noexcept
    {
        return (' ' == ch) ? t_Accum{1} : t_Accum{0};
    }

    public: auto operator ()(t_Accum const accum1, t_Accum const accum2) const noexcept
    {
        return accum1 + accum2;
    }

    public: auto operator ()(char const ch, t_Accum const accum) const noexcept
    {
        return accum + (*this)(ch);
    }

    public: auto operator ()(t_Accum const accum, char const ch) const noexcept
    {
        return accum + (*this)(ch);
    }

    public: auto operator ()(char const ch1, char const ch2) const noexcept
    {
        return (*this)(ch1) + (*this)(ch2);
    }
};

auto CountWords(::std::string_view str)
{
    return ::std::reduce(str.begin(), str.end(), t_Accum{0}, t_CountSpaces{});
}

int main()
{
    // должно вывести 6
    ::std::cout << CountWords("pretty little octopus dnskdj kjanfkj snfs jknds") << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/bYPo7rhT4)

А еще стоит отметить, что ни то, ни другое не могут быть использованы в `CountWords` для подсчета количества слов. По сути тут считается не количество слов, а количество пробелов (для этого подошел бы `::std::count`).

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить что именно делает функтор в reduce? Что есть первый элемент в функторе, для чего он?  Чем обобщенная сумма отличается от того, что делает accumulate? Требования алгоритма тоже не понятно что имеется ввиду.

Comment: И как все таки добиться результата с помощью reduce?

Comment: Разве первый параметр бинарной операции std::reduce не аккумулятор? А что тогда?

Comment: И еще, самое главное - ошибка в данном коде возникает только в GCC, а в clang все нормально. Почему так?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вы пишете: «При вызове reduce в функтор и первым, и вторым аргументом могут подавать и накопитель и символы.» То есть, получается, невозможно узнать где в данный момент накопитель, а где символ?

Comment: Аккумулятора при вызове  функтора в `reduce` может вообще не быть, а чтобы различать, где аккумулятор, а где выходящий элемент, следует делать соотв. перегрузки, что я и сделал в примере.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Теперь все предельно ясно.

Comment: на счет того что - "ни то, ни другое не могут быть использованы в CountWords для подсчета количества слов" - CountWords и должен считать пробелы, но - если подряд идущих пробелов нет, то CountWords считает слова. А что с поддержкой параллельности лучше подходит для подсчета слов в строке, если подряд идущих пробелов может быть несколько?

Comment: user7860670, алгоритм std::plus<>(), если использовать его в качестве функтора, будет работать по тому же принципу, что вы описали - с перегрузкой параметров?

Comment: Нет, количество пробелов не равно количеству слов. В примере из вопроса пробелов 6, а слов 7. А если бы пробелы были в начале и в конце, то их было бы 8. reduce в принципе можно было бы использовать для подсчета слов, если бы он не требовал коммутативности операции. `std::plus` не использует аккумулятора и годится разве что для складывания чаров. Так что вперед за сторонними библиотеками либо строить велосипеды.

Comment: Но std::plus свертку, например, последовательности целых чисел выполнит корректно? Имею ввиду, сложить все числа последовательности std::plus сможет? Какие последствия от того, что std::plus не использует аккумулятор?